como establecer un tamaño fijo de una carta con tailwind
muy buenas, me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto con php, la cuestion esque quiero que la estructura de una carta mantenga el mismo tamaño, independientemente del tamaño de la imagen que se agregue , adjunto la estructura de la carta en tailwind que tengo actualmente y una imagen para dar a entender lo que quiero evitar con mi diseño, como podria mantener el mismo tamaño para todas las cartas, sin importar el tamaño de la imagen? 


<!--offer wrapper-->
<div class="flex flex-center items-center mx-auto px-12 py-12 gap-8 justify-center">

  {{foreach ps4Products}}
  <!--card -->
  <div class="w-54 max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow ">

    <a href="#">
      <img class="p-8 rounded-t-lg mx-auto" src="/{{~BASE_DIR}}/imagenes/{{productoImagen}}" alt="product image" />
    </a>
    <div class="px-5 pb-5">
      <a href="#">
        <h5 class="text-xl text-center font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
          {{productoNombre}} - {{plataformaNombre}} </h5>
      </a>
      <div class="flex items-center mt-2.5 mb-5 justify-center">
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-1 rtl:space-x-reverse">
          <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-yellow-300" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 20">
                                                        <path d="M20.924 7.625a1.523 1.523 0 0 0-1.238-1.044l-5.051-.734-2.259-4.577a1.534 1.534 0 0 0-2.752 0L7.365 5.847l-5.051.734A1.535 1.535 0 0 0 1.463 9.2l3.656 3.563-.863 5.031a1.532 1.532 0 0 0 2.226 1.616L11 17.033l4.518 2.375a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 2.226-1.617l-.863-5.03L20.537 9.2a1.523 1.523 0 0 0 .387-1.575Z"/>
                                                </svg>
          <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-yellow-300" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 20">
                                                        <path d="M20.924 7.625a1.523 1.523 0 0 0-1.238-1.044l-5.051-.734-2.259-4.577a1.534 1.534 0 0 0-2.752 0L7.365 5.847l-5.051.734A1.535 1.535 0 0 0 1.463 9.2l3.656 3.563-.863 5.031a1.532 1.532 0 0 0 2.226 1.616L11 17.033l4.518 2.375a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 2.226-1.617l-.863-5.03L20.537 9.2a1.523 1.523 0 0 0 .387-1.575Z"/>
                                                </svg>
          <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-yellow-300" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 20">
                                                        <path d="M20.924 7.625a1.523 1.523 0 0 0-1.238-1.044l-5.051-.734-2.259-4.577a1.534 1.534 0 0 0-2.752 0L7.365 5.847l-5.051.734A1.535 1.535 0 0 0 1.463 9.2l3.656 3.563-.863 5.031a1.532 1.532 0 0 0 2.226 1.616L11 17.033l4.518 2.375a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 2.226-1.617l-.863-5.03L20.537 9.2a1.523 1.523 0 0 0 .387-1.575Z"/>
                                                </svg>
          <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-yellow-300" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 20">
                                                        <path d="M20.924 7.625a1.523 1.523 0 0 0-1.238-1.044l-5.051-.734-2.259-4.577a1.534 1.534 0 0 0-2.752 0L7.365 5.847l-5.051.734A1.535 1.535 0 0 0 1.463 9.2l3.656 3.563-.863 5.031a1.532 1.532 0 0 0 2.226 1.616L11 17.033l4.518 2.375a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 2.226-1.617l-.863-5.03L20.537 9.2a1.523 1.523 0 0 0 .387-1.575Z"/>
                                                </svg>
          <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-200 dark:text-gray-600" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 20">
                                                        <path d="M20.924 7.625a1.523 1.523 0 0 0-1.238-1.044l-5.051-.734-2.259-4.577a1.534 1.534 0 0 0-2.752 0L7.365 5.847l-5.051.734A1.535 1.535 0 0 0 1.463 9.2l3.656 3.563-.863 5.031a1.532 1.532 0 0 0 2.226 1.616L11 17.033l4.518 2.375a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 2.226-1.617l-.863-5.03L20.537 9.2a1.523 1.523 0 0 0 .387-1.575Z"/>
                                                </svg>
        </div>
        <span class="bg-blue-100 text-blue-800 text-xs font-semibold px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-blue-200 dark:text-blue-800 ms-3">5.0</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-col">
        <span class="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900 dark:text-white pb-5">${{productoPrecio}}.00</span>

        <div>
          <button type="button" class="text-white bg-secundary font-medium rounded-full text-sm px-12 py-2 text-center inline-flex items-center me-2 ">
                <svg class="w-3.5 h-3.5 me-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 18 21"> <path d="M15 12a1 1 0 0 0 .962-.726l2-7A1 1 0 0 0 17 3H3.77L3.175.745A1 1 0 0 0 2.208 0H1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h.438l.6 2.255v.019l2 7 .746 2.986A3 3 0 1 0 9 17a2.966 2.966 0 0 0-.184-1h2.368c-.118.32-.18.659-.184 1a3 3 0 1 0 3-3H6.78l-.5-2H15Z"/></svg> Comprar
           </button>
       </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--card end-->
  {{endfor ps4Products}}
</div>
<!--offer wrapper end-->




Para lo que propones, una opcion es jugar con object-cover y max-h, clases de tailwind las cuales te permitiran adaptar la imagen al contenido de la tarjeta sin perder su relacion de aspecto (que no se vea feo) y marcar un heigh o alto de la imagen maximo.
Seria algo asi:
...
<a href="#">
      <img class="p-8 rounded-t-lg mx-auto object-cover max-h-64" src="/{{~BASE_DIR}}/imagenes/{{productoImagen}}" alt="product image" />
</a>
...

He incluido dichas clases a tu imagen y de esta forma, todas las imagenes deberian de tener el mismo size y no romperse.
PD: Veo en tu codigo que estas utilizando un h5 para los titulos de tus tarjetas. Bajo mi punto de vista, esto es una mala practica y te recomendaria que usaras una etiqueta un poco mayor aunque tailwind elimine los estilos por defecto.
Un saludo, cualquier duda dejala por los comentarios!
